# How do I launch an EXE from Flash SWF using ActionScript?

Tags: flash, actionscript, executable

I want my Flash SWF to open an external EXE from the native operating system and I have tried:

```
protected function LaunchExe():void {
    flash.system.fscommand("exec","Test.exe");
}
```

But nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong with this command or do I need to something entirely differently?

Comment: Just wondering if you ever go the answer to this? I'm trying to open up a .exe file using a button in my Flash project, any help appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: No, I did not. Kind of gave up on that feature for my app. Sorry.

Comment: ah okay, I managed to sort it in the end now anyway, Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 2):

It works only from within a projector file (executable Flash), and if you are running it like that, the application you are trying to launch should be in a subdirectory called *fscommand*.

From [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package.html):

> The exec command runs in the subdirectory fscommand only. In other words, if you use the exec command to call an application, the application must reside in a subdirectory named fscommand. The exec command works only from within a Flash projector file.

Comment: I see, this is helpful but it appears I cannot generate a projector file from my Flex Flash Project in Flash Builder. Do you know of a way I can do that?

Comment: I've never used Flash Builder, but by projector file I mean that it has to be a .EXE for Windows or a .APP for Mac.  I believe Flash Builder only generates those kinds of files.  On Flash, a projector file is generated by going to *File/Publish Settings...* and selecting *Windows Projector* or *Macintosh Projector* from the *Format* tab.