# How do I launch a .exe file with a button click from my flash file using actionscript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I want to call my exe file whenever I click the button. I am currently using flash CS5.5.someone,please help me?

Comment: You can't. Imagine the security repercussions if people could create SWF files that could launch arbitrary programs... What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I launch an EXE from Flash SWF using ActionScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551543/how-do-i-launch-an-exe-from-flash-swf-using-actionscript)

Comment: you need to use a projector, or AIR if want the power to launch executables. Are you using either of those?

Comment: You sure can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

As a web application, this is not possible.

Although I would advise against this strategy, you could accomplish this if you target AIR or projector.

Both have caveats, so be sure to understand the technical constraints of each.

#### Projector

Project uses the [`flash.system`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package.html) package to execute [`fscommand`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package.html#fscommand()).

```
import flash.system.fscommand;
fscommand("exec", "app.exe");
```

#### AIR

AIR applications should use the [`flash.desktop`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/package-detail.html) package to invoke a [`NativeProcess`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html).

[*NativeProcessExample.as*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html#includeExamplesSummary) example, per the Adobe ASDoc page:

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
import flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.NativeProcessExitEvent;
import flash.filesystem.File;

public class NativeProcessExample extends Sprite {
    public var process:NativeProcess;

    public function NativeProcessExample() {
        if (NativeProcess.isSupported) {
            setupAndLaunch();
        }
        else {
            trace("NativeProcess not supported.");
        }
    }

    public function setupAndLaunch():void {
        var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("test.py");
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;

        var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
        processArgs[0] = "foo";
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;

        process = new NativeProcess();
        process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
        process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
        process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onErrorData);
        process.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onExit);
        process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_IO_ERROR, onIOError);
        process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_IO_ERROR, onIOError);
    }

    public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void {
        trace("Got: ", process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable));
    }

    public function onErrorData(event:ProgressEvent):void {
        trace("ERROR -", process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable));
    }

    public function onExit(event:NativeProcessExitEvent):void {
        trace("Process exited with ", event.exitCode);
    }

    public function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace(event.toString());
    }
}
}
```